# how to generate different color images according to one image in java or python?

Tags: java, python, image, image-processing

I want to generate some images in different color according to one image.But I couldn't find some resources about this.Could you recommand some useful reference material about how to implement by using java or python.

for example,the images below is generated from one image.
[image]

Comment: you could use opencv with python (they should exists for java too, but I'm not sure) . With them can manipulate color spaces and values, but i'm not sure this will solve the case with different "petals" color of those images..

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can take the help of the Image module to do this stuff.

For example -

```
import Image
picture = Image.open("/path/to/my/picture.jpg")
r,g,b = picture.getpixel( (0,0) )
print("Red: {0}, Green: {1}, Blue: {2}".format(r,g,b))
```

This above code will give you information about the pixel at (0,0)

```
import Image
picture = Image.open("/path/to/my/picture.jpg")

# Get the size of the image
width, height = picture.size()

# Process every pixel
for x in width:
    for y in height:
        # get pixel color
        current_color = picture.getpixel( (x,y) )

        # your main logic here to choose new color

        # put the new color on the pixel
        picture.putpixel( (x,y), new_color)
```

Comment: but how can I make the space which in same color in old image can keep same in new image?

Comment: @mengying.ye you need to check the different colors in the picture. I can only see 4 colors - White, Black, 1st petal color, 2nd petal color. 

If it is white or black, do not do anything.
If it is 1st color, set newcolor to what you desire and same for the last variety of color in the image.